# Fascinating, ma'am

Tags: beginner, sql, sql-server, stackexchange

Finding a famous question with high score I haven't voted on yet was proving to be a bit difficult for me. So I came up with this [simple SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/258927/fascinating-maam) to find good candidates:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
  Id AS [Post Link], ViewCount
FROM Posts
WHERE ViewCount >= 10000 AND Score >= 25
ORDER BY ViewCount DESC
```

Can this be improved in any way? (Btw, I'm a total noob with SEDE.)

Comment: Just an observation: this query relies on the fact that answers have `NULL` as the `ViewCount`.

Comment: [You can get pretty close to this without writing any SQL at all](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=views%3a10000%20score%3a25)

Comment: Can't sort by views though on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## General Feedback

With a query this short it's hard to go wrong, and you haven't. The formatting is consistently `SHOUTCASE` for keywords, as per convention. And there is nothing glaringly wrong at all.

I really can't find anything to complain about, you've got a nice query.

## A Small Suggestion

Have you considered adding parameters to the query. That way if you, or someone else, want to run using different numbers for the minimum `ViewCount` or `Score` then they wouldn't need to alter the query.

SEDE provides a special syntax for parameters, which looks like this:
`##MinViewCount:int?10000##`
where `MinViewCount` is the parameter name, `int` is the data type and 5 is the default value

```
SELECT TOP 10 
  Id AS [Post Link], ViewCount
FROM Posts
WHERE ViewCount >= ##MinBadges:int?5## 
AND Score >= ##MinBadges:int?5##
ORDER BY ViewCount DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the parameterization tip, that's exactly the kind of feedback I was hoping for, as I'm a total noob with SEDE!